# Rails: Cannot Parse XML Response using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, api, nokogiri

I'm basically trying to get the Lyric tag from the response I make to the ChartLyrics API. Here is the code I've written:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

request = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/GetLyric?lyricId=1710&lyricCheckSum=a4a56a99ee00cd8e67872a7764d6f9c6'))
puts request
response = Nokogiri::XML(request)

puts response.xpath("//Lyric")[0].to_s
```

I've read to the documentation but I did not find an answer. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
xml_doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/GetLyric?lyricId=1710&lyricCheckSum=a4a56a99ee00cd8e67872a7764d6f9c6'))
#I always prefer css than xpath
lyrics = xml_doc.css('Lyric')
if lyrics.empty?
  puts "COuld not find any lyric in the XML document'
else
  puts lyrics[0].to_s
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one more question. Is it possible to remove "Lyric" tags from the `lyrics` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Do response.remove_namespaces! before response.xpath